# How to set Parameter Type 'body' in grape-swagger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, ruby-grape

In Swagger you have for Post or Put the option to enter a JSON in a body. And you have a nice Model and Model Schema.
I hassle around since hours to find out how to implement this with Rails, Grape and Grape-Swagger. The documentation is extremely basic as well as the examples. Any help appreciated.

This is what I have right now:

```
    params do
      requires :ticket_id, type: Integer, desc: "Ticket ID (case insensitive)"
      requires :body, type: String, desc: "ticket body" # <-- type should be body or something like this
    end
    put ':ticket_id' do
      ticket= Ticket.where(ticket_id: params[:ticket_id]).first
      if params[:body]
        body = JSON.parse(params[:body])
        description = body.map { |m| m[:description] }
        ticket_state = body.map { |m| m[:ticketState] }
        unless description.nil? or ticket_state.nil?
          ticket.description += description
          ticket.ticket_state = ticket_state
          ticket.change_date = Time.now
          ticket.save
        end
      end
      present ticket, with: API::V1::Entities::Ticket
    end
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this was possible when the original post was created but this solved the problem for me today:

```
params do
  optional :time, type: String, desc: 'Time string (ISO8601)', documentation: { param_type: 'body' }
end
```

It accepts this JSON in the body:

```
{
  "time": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
}
```

Comment: Super useful mate. I cant believe for all that README, they have not mentioned anywhere how to change the type to be in `body`. This effectively overrides the type of the parameter and works 100%. Entity system is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

With github master branch of grape-swagger, grape and grape-entity the following works for me:

```
class API::Entities::Request::Body < Grape::Entity
  expose :id, documentation: { type: 'integer', required: true }
end

class API::Entities::ResponseEntity< Grape::Entity
  expose :id, documentation: { type: 'integer', required: true }
end

desc 'Create batch',
      entity: API::Entities::ResponseEntity
params do
  optional :request, type: API::Entities::Request::Body, desc: '...'
end
post '/test' do
transformed_params = API::Entities::Request::Body.represent(params, serializable: true)
 {}
end
```

Comment: However if the param is required, the method returns "{ request is missing }". Right?